# How to correct missing class/method issue with Proguard.cfg

Tags: java, android, proguard, method-missing

I have a fairly large project that uses some reflection in the code. The line of code that is causing the following crash:

```
W/System.err(22122): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class com.DynaZu.Tracker.cd]
W/System.err(22122):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460) 
W/System.err(22122):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:588)
W/System.err(22122):    at com.DynaZu.Tracker.ItemAdapter.getView(SourceFile:356)
W/System.err(22122):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
```

Is the SourceFile:356 line:

```
try {
    itemViewHolder = mViewHolderClass.getDeclaredConstructor(item.getClass())
                       .newInstance(item);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

elsewhere in the file:

```
Class<? extends ItemViewHolder> mViewHolderClass;
```

and the item is one of several potential classes all derived from class Item.

When I look into dump.txt, etc... I see lots and lots of stuff I can't quite turn back into a specific directive for proguard.cfg. From dump.txt:

```
 + Methodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/cd.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V]
 + Methodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/cd.a ()Ljava/lang/String;]
 + Methodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/cd.equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z]
 + Methodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/cd.h ()J]
 + Methodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/cd.o ()Ljava/lang/String;]
 + Methodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/cd.p ()Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;]
 + Methodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/cd.q ()F]
 + Methodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/ce.a (J)Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;]
 + Methodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/ce.a (Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;)V]
 + InterfaceMethodref [com/DynaZu/Tracker/ac.a (IILcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;ZZ)V]
 + NameAndType [<init> (Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;)V]
 + NameAndType [a (IILcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;ZZ)V]
 + NameAndType [a (J)Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;]
 + NameAndType [a (Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;)V]
 + NameAndType [a Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;]
 + NameAndType [b (Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;I)V]
 + NameAndType [c Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;]
 + NameAndType [p ()Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;]
 + Utf8 [()Lcom/DynaZu/Tracker/cd;]
```

And for proguard.cfg I realize I want something like:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends Item
-keep class * extends Item
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.  For example, is there a way to turn of proguard for one java file or one section of this java file???

Looking into this, I believe I need to add something like:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.DynaZu.Tracker.TaskViewHolder
{
  <init>(com.DynaZu.Tracker.Task);
}
```

etc... BUT ProGuard complains these class are Unknown... ? So how should an existing class in the project be noted in proguard.cfg.  ??? I have also tried just the class name TaskViewHolder by itself.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by looking into the proguard/.. dump.txt and especially mapping.txt.
From there I understood how some of my classes were named.  So I added the following to my proguard.cfg:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.DynaZu.Tracker.ItemViewHolder$TaskViewHolder
{
  <init>(com.DynaZu.Tracker.Task);
}
-keepclassmembers class com.DynaZu.Tracker.ItemViewHolder$ProjectViewHolder
{
  <init>(com.DynaZu.Tracker.Project);
}
-keepclassmembers class com.DynaZu.Tracker.ItemViewHolder
{
  <init>(com.DynaZu.Tracker.Item);
}
-keep class com.DynaZu.Tracker.Item
-keep class com.DynaZu.Tracker.Task
-keep class com.DynaZu.Tracker.Project
```

Once I understood what was going on, it wasn't hard.  I hope this helps someone else with this difficultly.  I have to  say that having a community and the availability of Stack Overflow is a life saver!